# Json decoder error when loading a json file. While the File is validated as Json. in Python

Tags: python, json, file, validation

so I am opening a Json file and when I try to load the file to a variable I get an errr because it can't read the file. While I have validated (online) that the Json file is valid. I am using this code:

```
with open("messagesTest2.json") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file) <----- ERROR
    for p in data['commits']:
        print(p['message'])
```

And I get this error. While I have another json file that is also validated and this code works. But this file doesn't work. My guess is that somewhere in the file there is something that it cannot translate as json? Is the decoder's fault?

> in raw_decode
>       raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
>   json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Do you have any idea how to fix it? Keep in mind that the json file is valid else I'll have to show the file but I'll have to hide some data :D

The Json file (The urls/passwards/logins/etc have been replaced but the format remains the same) :

```
{
    "commits": [{
        "sha": "asjdaskldjkalsk",
        "node_id": "sakldjaskldjaskldjklas",
        "commit": {
            "author": {
                "name": "korki",
                "email": "korki@kth.se",
                "date": "2015-09-07T22:06:51Z"
            },
            "committer": {
                "name": "korki",
                "email": "korki@kth.se",
                "date": "2015-09-07T22:06:51Z"
            },
            "message": "Added LaTex template and instructions",
            "tree": {
                "sha": "askdljaskdlajsklda",
                "url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915"
            },
            "url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
            "comment_count": 0,
            "verification": {
                "verified": "False",
                "reason": "unsigned",
                "signature": "None",
                "payload": "None"
            }
        },
        "url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
        "html_url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
        "comments_url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
        "author": {
            "login": "korki",
            "id": 999,
            "node_id": "askljdklas==",
            "type": "User",
            "site_admin": "None"
        },
        "committer": {
            "login": "korki",
            "id": 999,
            "node_id": "askljdklas==",
            "type": "User",
            "site_admin": "None"
        },
        "parents": [{
            "sha": "asdaskldjasdklsjl",
            "url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
            "html_url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915"
        }]
    }, {
        "sha": "kasdjklasdjklas",
        "node_id": "sdklasjdklasjkl",
        "commit": {
            "author": {
                "name": "korki",
                "email": "korki@kth.se",
                "date": "2015-08-31T10:45:24Z"
            },
            "committer": {
                "name": "korki",
                "email": "korki@kth.se",
                "date": "2015-08-31T10:45:24Z"
            },
            "message": "Update README.md",
            "tree": {
                "sha": "askldjkasldjklas",
                "url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915"
            },
            "url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
            "comment_count": 0,
            "verification": {
                "verified": "None",
                "reason": "unsigned",
                "signature": "None",
                "payload": "None"
            }
        },
        "url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
        "html_url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
        "comments_url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
        "author": {
            "login": "korki",
            "id": 999,
            "node_id": "dkasdasdnas==",
            "type": "User",
            "site_admin": "None"
        },
        "committer": {
            "login": "korki",
            "id": 999,
            "node_id": "askldaskldja==",
            "type": "User",
            "site_admin": "None"
        },
        "parents": [{
            "sha": "dlkasdjklas;dlkjas;",
            "url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
            "html_url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915"
        }]
    }, {
        "sha": "dsagadsgsgdsa",
        "node_id": "sdagfsdgsd",
        "commit": {
            "author": {
                "name": "korki",
                "email": "korki@kth.se",
                "date": "2015-08-31T10:44:42Z"
            },
            "committer": {
                "name": "korki",
                "email": "korki@kth.se",
                "date": "2015-08-31T10:44:42Z"
            },
            "message": "Initial commit",
            "tree": {
                "sha": "asdasddasdas",
                "url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915"
            },
            "url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
            "comment_count": 0,
            "verification": {
                "verified": "None",
                "reason": "unsigned",
                "signature": "None",
                "payload": "None"
            }
        },
        "url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
        "html_url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
        "comments_url": "https://gits-15.ds.sd.se/04dd5b226dda1915",
        "author": {
            "login": "korki",
            "id": 999,
            "node_id": "kjklklj==",
            "type": "User",
            "site_admin": "None"
        },
        "committer": {
            "login": "korki",
            "id": 999,
            "node_id": "jhkjkj==",
            "gravatar_id": "",
            "type": "User",
            "site_admin": "None"
        },
        "parents": []
    }]
}
```

Comment: Whats the content of `messagesTest2.json`?

Comment: Its commits from github. Do you want to see a sample?

Comment: Can you provide some samples in the `messagesTest2.json` or at least some basic format.

Comment: Yeah second. :)

Comment: @Philipl added json.

Comment: @heemayl added json.

Answer (score 2):

That error means it is reading a blank file. Make sure you are reading the file you think you are reading.

EDIT: Another possibility is that you have already read through all the lines of the file. If you read through all the lines and try to read the file, it will appear as a blank file.

Comment: What do you mean? I might have spelled wrong the name of the file?

Comment: no the name file and everything is correct. Something is missing... Like a wrong encoder? Or I don't kow...

Comment: It is finding a file, but the file is blank. So yes, it is possible you have misspelled the filename, and it is now pointing to a blank file. You also might have forgotten to save. There's a bunch of ways this can happen.

Comment: I double/triple checked that from the begining. Assume that the file that I read is correct and we should focus on why does it read it as a blank.

Comment: Read all the lines? And why doens't it stop? I mean you see my file? You can make a json file of it. And can u check if u still get an errr like that? Or how can I solve that?

Comment: Did you really post all your code? Or is there anything between the first line and second line that you've removed?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. I used a powershell script to create a json file and I tried to read the file from another python script but I kept getting the same error as you, even though the JSON file was properly formatted. The issue was I was using a powershell command, "Out-File" Instead, I used Set-Content and it fixed the issue. I believe it was an encoding difference between the commands. Maybe look at how you created the JSON file and the encoding used. I know this is late but I'll share anyways just in case anyone else is having the same issue.

Comment: It will be better if you add a step-by-step procedure.